# "No tests found matching Method " error on CDC test with spring and pact

Tags: spring-test, pact, pact-jvm

I doing an CDC provider test with pact and spring, I was able to generate the pact file, 
but when I use the pact json for provider testing , it came out below error :"No tests found matching Method runTest", here is my code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRestPactRunner.class)
@Provider("myProvider")
@PactFolder("target/pacts")
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class ProviderTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController; # the controller I want to test
    @MockBean
    private MyService myService; # the dependency of controller

    @TestTarget
    public final Target target = new SpringBootHttpTarget();

    @State("my_state")
    public void runTest() {

    }
}
```

and the pact file is something like this:

```
... other parts
"providerStates": [
            {
                "name": "my_state"
            }
        ]
... other parts
```

it seems that my test cannot find the "my_state" ?

EDIT:
here is my demo project , Please help take a look, Thanks!
https://github.com/wuhuanxing/pact_demo

Comment: Run a whole class, not a single method.

Answer (score 0):

That pact is using version 3 of the pact specification. Make sure you're using the latest version of the pact jar to ensure it supports version 3. If you can create a reproducible example in a Github repository, you can ask for help on slack.pact.io.

Comment: I used the v3 of pact, and I just add the demo project , could u please take a look ,tanks